# Is there a more efficient way to calculate the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I used Gaussian Elimination to calculate $$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&4&9&16&25&36\\4&9&16&25&36&49\\9&16&25&36&49&64\\16&25&36&49&64&81\\25&36&49&64&81&100\\36&49&64&81&100&121\end{pmatrix}$$ and found the answer to be $0$. It took a lot of time to do.

The lower-upper (LU) decomposition is shown below. I think that there might be a more efficient way to calculate the determinant of this kind of matrix.

[image: LU decomposition]

Comment: Hint: the sequence of squares satisfies $k^2 - 3(k+1)^2 + 3(k+2)^2-(k+3)^2 = 0$.

Comment: Hint, If you subtract the first row from the second you get the sequence of odd integers, Look at other adjacent rows.

Comment: It seems like a circulant matrix.

Comment: @Moo Yes, I saw it. Thanks.

Comment: @Lelouch are you sure?

Comment: @DatBoi Rather an "anti" circulant matrix. The general formula still holds if we add a term for the sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A = \det\begin{pmatrix}1&4&9&16&25&36\\4&9&16&25&36&49\\9&16&25&36&49&64\\16&25&36&49&64&81\\25&36&49&64&81&100\\36&49&64&81&100&121\end{pmatrix}$$
By successively subtracting rows, we get

$R_5=R_5-R_4$, $R_4=R_4-R_3$, $R_3=R_3-R_2$, $R_2=R_2-R_4$,

$$A = \det\begin{pmatrix}1&4&9&16&25&36\\7&9&11&13&15&17\\9&11&13&15&17&19\\11&13&15&17&19&21\\13&15&17&19&21&23\\15&17&19&21&23&25\end{pmatrix}$$
We repeat the same again, we get
$R_5=R_5-R_4$, $R_4=R_4-R_3$

$$A = \det\begin{pmatrix}1&4&9&16&25&36\\7&9&11&13&15&17\\9&11&13&15&17&19\\11&13&15&17&19&21\\2&2&2&2&2&2\\2&2&2&2&2&2\end{pmatrix}$$

As $R_5=R_4$, by properties of determinants we conclude that the determinant is zero or $A = 0$

Comment: In the very last line, it says "det(A) = 0", but before you had introduced A as the number $A = \det \dots$.

Comment: My fellow told me just like you wrote. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly every row is part of the space of vectors $(a_1,\ldots,a_6)$ for which $a_i$ can be given by a polynomial expression in$~i$ of degree${}<3$ (i.e., with $a_i=p+qi+ri^2$ for some scalars $p,q,r$ and $0<i\leq 6$). That subspace of $\Bbb Q^6$ being of dimension$~3$, any $4$ or more rows are linearly dependent, so the determinant of the matrix must be$~0$ (and the rank of the matrix at most$~3$).

Answer (score 0):

Let us give your matrix a name:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&9&16&25&36\\4&9&16&25&36&49\\9&16&25&36&49&64\\16&25&36&49&64&81\\25&36&49&64&81&100\\36&49&64&81&100&121
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The decomposition $A = LU$ (which you have found explicitly) is very helpful in this case. The upper right matrix ($U$) does not have full (row) rank, thus its determinant is $0$. Since the determinant is a multiplicative function, we get

$$
\det A = \det(L) \cdot \det(U) = \det(L) \cdot 0 = 0
$$